# How to add gridlines as !staticlayer to a MapFish3 print template?

Tags: printing, mapfish, config.yaml, print-templates

I am trying to add gridlines to a template by using a !staticlayer attribute with the !addBackgroundLayers processor. I am able to output a PDF map, however, no gridlines are visible.

Here is my config.yaml:

```
templates:

 #===========================================================================
 # Demo Template
 A4 landscape: !template
 #===========================================================================
reportTemplate: template.jrxml
attributes:
  title: !string {}
  subTitle: !string {}
  mapMain: !map
    maxDpi: 300
    width: 780
    height: 390
  overlayLayers: !staticLayers
    default:
      layers:
        - type: "grid"
          gridType: "lines"
          numberOfLines: [4, 4]
          labelColor: rgba(0,0,0,0)
          haloColor: rgba(0,0,0,0)
  scalebar: !scalebar
    width: 240
    height: 40
    default:
      type: line
      unit: m
      orientation: "horizontalLabelsAbove"
      renderAsSvg: true
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
      align: "right"

processors:
- !reportBuilder # compile all reports in current directory
  directory: '.'
- !createMap
  inputMapper: {mapMain: map}
  outputMapper: {mapSubReport: map}
- !addBackgroundLayers
  inputMapper: {
                overlayLayers: staticLayers,
                mapMain: map
               }
- !createScalebar {}
```

All the other items on my map appear as expected (scalebar, title, etc). I have only been successful in applying gridlines to the map by passing the gridlayer in the requestData json.

Answer (score -1):

exchange the "!addBackgroundLayers" with "!addOverlayLayers", that did it for me